# Using lxml & django/python - list index out of range

Tags: python, django, django-views, lxml

I have a small issue.  I am trying to pull some data from my XML using lxml and I keep getting a "list index out of range" error,  now I am trying to get the [0] position of my list, which should be the first one but it keeps giving me the error.

Here is a code snippet (thanks to MattH for helping me out):

```
req2 = urllib2.Request("web_url/public/api.php?path_info=/projects&token=##############")
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(req2)
        resp_data = resp.read()
        if not resp.code == 200 and resp.headers.get('content-type') == 'text/xml':
          # Do your error handling.
          raise Exception('Unexpected response',req2,resp)
        data = etree.XML(resp_data)
        api_id = int(data.xpath('/project/id/text()')[0])
        project.API_id = api_id
        project.save()
```

Now when I do a print statement, it pulls the XML so I know that I have xml data and its not blank, but not sure what else could be causing this?

Thanks!

Steve

Comment: What is the XML structure ("project" and "id" are elements, right?!)? What does `print repr(data.xpath('/project/id/text()')))` output?

Comment: structure is as follows:
<projects>
<project>
<id></id>
</project>
</projects>

Comment: when trying print repr(data.xpath('/project/id/text()')) ... it outputs '[]'

Comment: BTW you're missing parentheses: `if not resp.code == 200 and resp.headers.get('content-type') == 'text/xml':`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your XML document's structure being

```xml
<projects>
    <projects>
        <id>
            ...
        </id>
    </project>
</projects>
```

your XPath expression `/project/id/text()` surely won't match anything, and the accessing index 0 of the empty XPath result list of course results in an `IndexError`.

Instead of `/project`, which only matches a root (!) element called "project", you might want to use `/projects/project` or `//project`. So a correct XPath for your XML structure would be `//project/id/text()`.

Comment: thanks AndiDog, that seemed to work.  I see now what you were saying, I didn't go deep enough into the XML, so thats why I was getting the index error.  One least question, is there any way to find the most recent entry?